# Intercepting Touch Event Nested Scroll View EditTexts and Spinners

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-scrollview, motionevent

I have a Fragment with a couple of EditTexts, Spinners and SeekBars, and before you know it, it's really hard to find a piece of whitespace to be able to scroll inside the NestedScrollView. It makes the UI feel very broken.

I'm not sure if it is a bug, or because the Support library isn't complete yet, but I would like to find a way to force the EditTexts and Spinners to only intercept Clicks and LongClicks. It seems Scroll events are being ignored.

Edit: Feel a little bit silly here, but I nailed down the cause. I had an element in my Layout that was set to Visibility.Gone. When it was GONE, the scrolling didn't work correctly. Now that I have made it VISIBLE, I'm not having any scrolling issues.

Bug perhaps?

Here's the onInterceptTouchEvent for the NestedScrollView (part of the Support library)

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    /*
     * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
     * If we return true, onMotionEvent will be called and we do the actual
     * scrolling there.
     */

    /*
    * Shortcut the most recurring case: the user is in the dragging
    * state and he is moving his finger.  We want to intercept this
    * motion.
    */
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && (mIsBeingDragged)) {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Don't try to intercept touch if we can't scroll anyway.
     */
    if (getScrollY() == 0 && !ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(this, 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            /*
             * mIsBeingDragged == false, otherwise the shortcut would have caught it. Check
             * whether the user has moved far enough from his original down touch.
             */

            /*
            * Locally do absolute value. mLastMotionY is set to the y value
            * of the down event.
            */
            final int activePointerId = mActivePointerId;
            if (activePointerId == INVALID_POINTER) {
                // If we don't have a valid id, the touch down wasn't on content.
                break;
            }

            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, activePointerId);
            if (pointerIndex == -1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid pointerId=" + activePointerId
                        + " in onInterceptTouchEvent");
                break;
            }

            final int y = (int) MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);
            final int yDiff = Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);
            if (yDiff > mTouchSlop
                    && (getNestedScrollAxes() & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) == 0) {
                mIsBeingDragged = true;
                mLastMotionY = y;
                initVelocityTrackerIfNotExists();
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);
                mNestedYOffset = 0;
                final ViewParent parent = getParent();
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final int y = (int) ev.getY();
            if (!inChild((int) ev.getX(), (int) y)) {
                mIsBeingDragged = false;
                recycleVelocityTracker();
                break;
            }

            /*
             * Remember location of down touch.
             * ACTION_DOWN always refers to pointer index 0.
             */
            mLastMotionY = y;
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);

            initOrResetVelocityTracker();
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);
            /*
            * If being flinged and user touches the screen, initiate drag;
            * otherwise don't.  mScroller.isFinished should be false when
            * being flinged.
            */
            mIsBeingDragged = !mScroller.isFinished();
            startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            /* Release the drag */
            mIsBeingDragged = false;
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
            recycleVelocityTracker();
            stopNestedScroll();
            break;
        case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            onSecondaryPointerUp(ev);
            break;
    }

    /*
    * The only time we want to intercept motion events is if we are in the
    * drag mode.
    */
    return mIsBeingDragged;
}
```

I would imagine that should forcibly intercept Scroll actions, but it doesn't seem to be.

This is the onTouchEvent for the MaterialEditText that I am using:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (singleLineEllipsis && getScrollX() > 0 && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getX() < getPixel(4 * 5) && event.getY() > getHeight() - extraPaddingBottom - innerPaddingBottom && event.getY() < getHeight() - innerPaddingBottom) {
        setSelection(0);
        return false;
    }
    if (hasFocus() && showClearButton) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (insideClearButton(event)) {
                    clearButtonTouched = true;
                    clearButtonClicking = true;
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (clearButtonClicking && !insideClearButton(event)) {
                    clearButtonClicking = false;
                }
                if (clearButtonTouched) {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (clearButtonClicking) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getText())) {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                    clearButtonClicking = false;
                }
                if (clearButtonTouched) {
                    clearButtonTouched = false;
                    return true;
                }
                clearButtonTouched = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                clearButtonTouched = false;
                clearButtonClicking = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

and for the MaterialSpinner:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (isEnabled()) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                isSelected = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                isSelected = false;
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Is there anything obvious there that should be telling me why Scroll Motion Events are not being handled properly?

Edit: I'm not sure I can explain this properly, but it seems that if the ErrorTexts are showing for at least one item in each horizontal layout, that the scrolling works properly. Will investigate further...